# How can I set a userId inside the users object when an icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a mock userId which should be saved inside the `users` object of the `reactions` object when a certain icon is clicked inside my react component.

Below is a function `updateUploadReaction` that is supposed to do that for me. The logic is this, when an icon is clicked and this particular userId does not exist in the `users` object, it sets it inside the `user` object and adds 1, on clicking again it sets it to false and subtracts 1. So far, this is what I have, but it simply keeps subtracting `3` each time I click. I need a guide on exactly how to do that.

Here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/infinity-web-development/ratethis/tree/bug/Chioma/user_uploads) to the full App. `updateUploadReaction` is inside `components/home/reducers.js`

reaction object

```
{

        reactions: {
            dislike: {
                count: 0,
                users: {},
            },
            like: {
                count: 0,
                users: {},
            },
            maybe: {
                count: 0,
                users: {},
            },
        },

}
```

function

```
function updateUploadReaction(id, type, uploads) {
    const updatedUploads = new Map([...uploads.entries()]);
    const upload = updatedUploads.get(id);
    const userId = uuid();

    uploads.forEach(() => {
        if (!userId {
            upload.reactions[type].count += 1;
            upload.reactions[type]..users[userId] = true;
        } else {
            upload.reactions[type].count -= 1;
            upload.reactions[type].users[userId] = false;
        }
    });

    updatedUploads.set(id, upload);

    return updatedUploads;
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that your forEach is subtracting the count once for each upload you have, which is three right? You need to rethink that function.

Comment: Also your headline and description are asking different questions. And it seems like you are passing the same userId into each user in upload. You need to call ```uuid()``` in the forEach loop. I would create a different function altogether that handles whether or not those userId is true or false.

Comment: May I get a quick guide on that @cullanrocks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this, I'm not sure if you want to add a new userId and remove it, or do something else. Perhaps it is an array of userIds? I think this might help you get on the right track though:

```js
const upload1 = {
  reactions: {
    dislike: {
      count: 0,
      users: { userId: 1 },
    },
  },
}
const upload2 = {
  reactions: {
    dislike: {
      count: 0,
      users: {},
    },
  },
}

const uploads = [ upload1, upload2 ];

const updateObjectReaction = ( id, type, uploads ) => {
 uploads.forEach( upload => {
  const { users } = upload.reactions[ type ]
  if ( Object.values( users ).includes( id ) ) {
   delete users.userId
  }
  else {
   users.userId = id;
  }
 } );
 console.log( { upload1Users: uploads[ 0 ].reactions.dislike.users } )
 console.log( { upload2Users: uploads[ 1 ].reactions.dislike.users } )
}

updateObjectReaction( 1, "dislike", uploads )
```